# Best way to supply heaters for VFD tube

Tags: vacuum-fluorescent

Building a simple VFD clock with 4x IV-22 tubes. The heaters run at 1 to 1.32v @ 100mA each.
Whats the best way to supply power to the heaters?

All the heaters need to be in parallel so that their potential is the same relative to the grids and segments.

Thats ~1.3v @ 400mA. for 5V supply a resistor would need to dissapate 1/2W. That seems wasteful.

Is it possible to use the MCU to generate a PWM signal to drive the heaters directly? Then how does the current get limited (is P now 2W = 5v * 400mA?) The heater in VFD tubes is both a heater and a cathode, it has to be hot and at 1v potential to emit electrons, right, but not too hot to limit its life?

Maybe there is a way to generate AC waveform to eliminate luminance slant of segments on one side?

Also, as a side question, while I have attracted the attention of VFD knowledgeable people: For internally non-multiplexed tubes such as IV-22 what is the purpose of the grid? When would you ever want to keep it low on a single digit tube? Am I OK just wiring all the grids together into VBB (the 30V supply)?

**Update:** Thanks for the comments. To clarify further I will be powering this from a low voltage PSU, 12 or 9V DC so I won't have a transformer to tap from. Any voltages higher than supply will be made using Boost DC converters.

Comment: Have you looked into a buck converter? 1.2V buck converters are *all* over the place.

Comment: If you want to keep it simple, a PWM could work but the 5v supply would need be able to supply the full current for the on duration...

Comment: PWM via a transformer, that would give low current from the 5V supply. Centre tap the transformer and you can also avoid the bias on one side of the heater.

Comment: @Dave: Thats interesting, but what about the current limitation, and making the output swing in reverse too? I have found LM9022 (dedicated VFD heater driver) too, and people seem to be replacing it with a push pull mosfet driver. Is there some trick with the heater that i'm missing?

Comment: @MadHatter If I use the PWM signal to switch a transistor that would source enough current. Do I need to limit the current?

Comment: @YarekT, heaters are resistive elements that produce heat. P=(I^2)*R. DC makes heat just as well as AC. If you're dead set using an AC waveform, you could always make an oscillator and have it drive transistors from the 1.2V power source you just got from DC buck. *As for how it limits,* it's a thermo-resistive property of the material that they make heaters out of. I.E. the heaters self limit to 400mA if you put in 1.3V (they're resisters honestly). *Regarding the LM9022,* that produces all the voltages you need from one 5V source. You could replace it with transistors and passive components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 400mA [buck converter](http://www.skyworksinc.com/uploads/documents/202005A.pdf) would probably be easiest. As below, alter the resistor values to get your desired nominal filament voltage. Simple, cheap and tiny.

[image]

---

You could also whack the filaments with the full input voltage (anodes off) at very low duty cycle but that's kind of ugly and if anything sticks on (such as your micro freezing) your VFD filaments will quickly die. At 9V in to get 1.2V RMS at the filaments your duty cycle would be

\$\frac{t_{ON}}{t_{OFF}+t_{ON}} = \frac{1.2^2}{9^2} \approx 1.5 \% \$

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the heater needs AC voltage (for heating) and a DC bias, otherwise you'll see uneven illumination. A flyback with a separate mid-tapped winding for heater is usually used, but I can't give you part numbers you could easily order.